# Incorrect syntax near '2021'. (102) using pyodbc to insert a datetime object into a SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime2

I am trying to insert the current datetime into a `datetime2` type column of a SQL Server table:

```
creationdatetime = datetime.datetime.now() # 2021-11-20 21:35:40.851495

sql = ("INSERT INTO [SCHEMA].[TABLE] (\n"
        "[CreationDateTime]) \n"
        f"VALUES ('{creationdatetime}')")

cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()
```

I keep on getting this error:

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '2021'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)

Already spent like 3 hours to fix this issue....

Any help is really appreciated

Thank you

Comment: If you parametrise, rather than inject, this issue disappears. Plus your code then doesn't have a huge security vulnerability. Learn from the mistakes of others from the last decades: Parametrise.

Comment: After parametrisation it worked fine, Thank you

Comment: You could add the updated, parametrized code as an answer and as an example for others who might be facing the same issue

Comment: @Anouar can you please update your what worked for you?